# Strange WSDL warning during validation in Eclispe: "wsdl:operation was not a request/response or one-way operation"

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a WSDL file and I can't get rid of this warning from the Eclipse validator:

```
WS-I: (BP2208) wsdl:operation was not a request/response or one-way operation.
```

This is the WSDL source I wrote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<definitions name="Master"
    targetNamespace="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth"
    xmlns:tns="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth"

    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <types>
        <xs:schema 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0"
        targetNamespace="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth"
        xmlns:tns="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth">

            <xs:element name="AccessDB" type="tns:AccessDBType">
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE AccessDBType -->

            <xs:element name="passThrough" type="tns:passThroughType"/>
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE passThroughType -->

        </xs:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="updatedDB">
        <part name="db" element="tns:AccessDB"/>
    </message>

    <message name="passThroughNotice">
        <part name="info" element="tns:passThrough"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="myPorts">
        <operation name="updateManager">
            <output name="newUpdate" message="tns:updatedDB"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="noticeManager">
            <input name="newNotice" message="tns:passThroughNotice"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="myBindings" type="tns:myPorts">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="updateManager">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="noticeManager">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="MyServices">
        <port name="ACSAuth" binding="tns:myBindings">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8181/ACSAuth"/>
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

Here you can find the complete WSDL file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33459047/StackOverflow/Master.wsdl

I believe that the source of the problem is the operation "updateManager", but I don't know how to fix it.
Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An endpoint can support 4 types of operations. From the [WSDL specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_porttypes):

> WSDL has four transmission primitives that an endpoint can support:
>
> - **One-way**. The endpoint receives a message.
> - **Request-response**. The endpoint receives a message, and sends a correlated message.
> - **Solicit-response**. The endpoint sends a message, and receives a correlated message.
> - **Notification**. The endpoint sends a message.

The WS-I Profile seems to have a rule for supporting only two of them. [From WS-I, Test Assertion: BP2208](http://www.ws-i.org/Testing/Tools/2005/01/BP11_TAD_1-1.htm):

> **Context:**
>   
> For a candidate wsdl:operation in a wsdl:portType definition
>
> **Assertion Description:**
>   
> The wsdl:operation element is either a WSDL request/response or a one-way operation (no Notification or Sollicit-Response).
>
> **Failure Message:**
>   
> wsdl:operation was not a request/response or one-way operation.

Your `updateManager` operation is a `Notification` and from here your warning.

Clearing the error depends on you [interoperability compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950938/why-is-it-important-to-be-ws-i-basic-profile-compliant/) needs. You can either ignore the warning (and then your service won't be 100% interoperability compliant) or you can fix it by changing the operation type (which depends on your application).

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer, it really helped me a lot! The problem is that I have to solve a specific scenario and I can't change how the web-services must be implemented.
Also I have another problem (an error, not just a warning) with a solicit-response operation, is it due to the same problem you described? Here are the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196171/cant-implement-solicit-response-wsdl-operation-in-eclipse

Comment: I ended up changing the operation type. Again, thank you a lot for the explanation. Bye!