# Can't implement solicit-response WSDL operation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm writing a WSDL file and I get this error from the Eclipse validator:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'input'.
One of '{"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":fault}' is expected.
```

This is the WSDL source I wrote, the line where the Eclipse validator gives me the error is in the `<operation name="bootstrap">` element:

```
<definitions name="Slave"
    targetNamespace="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth"
    xmlns:tns="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth"

    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <types>
        <xs:schema 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0"
        targetNamespace="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth"
        xmlns:tns="http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth">

            <xs:element name="isAuthQuery" type="tns:authRequestType" />
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE authRequestType -->
            <xs:element name="isAuthReply" type="tns:authReplyType" />
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE authReplyType -->
            <xs:element name="isAuthError" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="newSlave" type="tns:requestNewDB"/>
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE requestNewDB -->
            <xs:element name="errorBoot" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="AccessDB" type="tns:AccessDBType">
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE AccessDBType -->
            <xs:element name="passThrough" type="tns:passThroughType"/>
            <!-- OMITTED COMPLEX TYPE passThroughType -->
        </xs:schema>
    </types>

    <message name="askForAuth">
        <part name="query" element="tns:isAuthQuery"/>
    </message>

    <message name="replyForAuth">
        <part name="response" element="tns:isAuthReply"/>
    </message>

    <message name="errorForAuth">
        <part name="error" element="tns:isAuthError"/>
    </message>

    <message name="newSlave">
        <part name="newSlaveInfo" element="tns:newSlave"/>
    </message>

    <message name="updatedDB">
        <part name="db" element="tns:AccessDB"/>
    </message>

    <message name="errorBoot">
        <part name="error" element="tns:errorBoot"/>
    </message>

    <message name="passThroughNotice">
        <part name="info" element="tns:passThrough"/>
    </message>

    <portType name="myPorts">
        <operation name="isAuthorized">
            <input message="tns:askForAuth"/>
            <output message="tns:replyForAuth"/>
            <fault name="error" message="tns:errorForAuth"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="bootstrap">
            <output name="newSlave" message="tns:newSlave"/>
            <input name="newDB" message="tns:updatedDB"/>
            <fault name="error" message="tns:errorBoot"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="updateManager">
            <input name="newUpdate" message="tns:updatedDB"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getNotice">
            <input name="newNotice" message="tns:passThroughNotice"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>

    <binding name="myBindings" type="tns:myPorts">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="isAuthorized">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="error">
                <soap:fault name="error" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="bootstrap">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
                <!-- *** THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I GET THE ERROR *** -->
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <fault name="error">
                <soap:fault name="error" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="updateManager">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
        </operation>
        <operation name="getNotice">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="MyServices">
        <port name="ACSAuth" binding="tns:myBindings">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8181/ACSAuth"/>
        </port>
    </service>

</definitions>
```

Here you can find the complete WSDL file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33459047/StackOverflow/Slave.wsdl

Is this because the WS-I Profile supports only 2 of the 4 recommended primitives that an endpoint can support (and solicit-response is not one of them)? Or it just some stupid error I can't see (I already wasted a lot of time looking for a possible mistake of mine).
Can someone help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'll get the following error message on executing `wsdl2java -d test your.wsdl`: `WSDLToJava Error: Non-unique body parts! In a port, operations must have unique operation signatures on the wire for successful dispatching. In port {http://pad.politio.it/ACSAuth}ACSAuth, operations "{http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth}updateManager" and "{http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth}bootstrap" have the same request body block {http://pad.polito.it/ACSAuth}AccessDB`

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the operation type to request-response because of the missing implementation of the operation solicit-response in WS-I Profile.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189170/strange-wsdl-warning-during-validation-in-eclispe-wsdloperation-was-not-a-req), thanks to Bogdan.